# Turn bluetooth on when screen off and volume key is pressed

Tags: bluetooth, tasker, volume-control

I would like to be able to toggle bluetooth on when phone screen is off (locked) and I press the volume up button, ideally twice (two quick presses).

What options do I have to accomplish this on a rooted Android 7.1.2 phone? ROM is Ressurection Remix 5.8.5.

So far I tried Tasker with AutoInput plugin, but it only works when screen is on. Apparently AutoInput does not register keypresses when screen is off.

I also tried Xposed Additions, which does react to volume button when screen off, but I can not assign a Tasker action to it that enables the bluetooth. There are only a limited number of actions I can choose when screen is off.

Comment: In Xposed Additions, under "Add New Action", choose Shortcuts and than assign your Tasker shortcut there. See "Instructions to use Task shortcuts in Xposed Additions" heading in my answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277

Comment: Weird, I don't have the "Applications" section in the 'add new action' menu. I only have a "Custom actions" section with "disabled" and "torch" and a bunch more if I choose "screen on"